# ASP.NET Unable to resolve service for type, while attempting to activate controller

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

While I understand there were other questions on this very topic I was having a difficult time understanding the answers and was hoping someone could walk me through how DbContext's work as I feel I might have created a second context when I shouldn't have.

So, as I'm teaching myself more about .NET Core I'm working on turning an old school project into a .NET project which is a simple Dentist office web app where users can sign up for appointments, view their appointments, etc. I was following along with [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to add additional user attributes instead of just username & e-mail as I was trying to grab the current user when creating an appointment.

Before I added this custom attributes using the default IdentityUI I had my project working where a user could register and login, create a basic appointment with their 'username' pick a date and time and once created would display their appointments in a basic table format. My next step was to add the custom user attributes so it would display based on their real-name and not their username which is defaulted to their email.

Following the tutorial I'm not sure if I misunderstood but I created a new Context and IdentityUser which all worked but it has broken my 'Appointments' page giving me the:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'WelchDentistry.Controllers.AppointmentsController'.** error.

Here is my ConfigureServices method as I believe it's an issue in regards to registering the 2 different Contexts.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
        /*
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
                */
                
        /*
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            */

            
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Here is the original context

```
namespace WelchDentistry.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<WelchDentistry.Models.Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller for my appointments

```
namespace WelchDentistry.Controllers
{
    public class AppointmentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


        public AppointmentsController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
            

        // GET: Appointments
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            return View(await _context.Appointment.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Appointments/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var appointment = await _context.Appointment
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (appointment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(appointment);
        }

        // GET: Appointments/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Appointments/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID, CustomerName, AppointmentTime,CustomerDoctor")] Appointment appointment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(appointment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(appointment);
        }

        // GET: Appointments/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var appointment = await _context.Appointment.FindAsync(id);
            if (appointment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(appointment);
        }

        // POST: Appointments/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,CustomerName,AppointmentTime,CustomerDoctor")] Appointment appointment)
        {
            if (id != appointment.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(appointment);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!AppointmentExists(appointment.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(appointment);
        }

        // GET: Appointments/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var appointment = await _context.Appointment
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (appointment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(appointment);
        }

        // POST: Appointments/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var appointment = await _context.Appointment.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Appointment.Remove(appointment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool AppointmentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Appointment.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

If more code is needed please ask or you can view on [my Github](https://github.com/nwelch-dev/WelchDentistry)

I appreciate all the help and bare with my as I'm still lost on most of this but slowly learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove your IdentityHostingStartup file in your Identity Area.

Then change your databasecontext to this ( You should introduce your User class ) :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<WelchDentistryUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Models.Appointment> Appointment { get; set; }
}
```

And add this codes in your startup file .

```
        services.AddIdentity<WelchDentistryUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

And finally you should use your custom User class in controller.

```
public class AppointmentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<WelchDentistryUser> _userManager;


    public AppointmentsController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<WelchDentistryUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

}

Comment: If I could ask a follow up question, what is the purpose of removing the IdentityHostingStartup file as if I understand correctly that is registering our service granted I understand it was a duplicate of what was already in the Startup file, just trying to get a better understanding. Then, with editing my existing context does that mean I need to remove the newly created context?

Comment: With IdentityHostingStartup you register dependencies twice and so your get error . You should either register your  identity dependencies in Startup or in the IdentityHostingStartup . It's your choice .

Comment: Really appreciate it! Project is back working! So was I incorrect in creating a new context with adding custom attributes to the default user? Could I have done that using the existing DbContext or did I still go through the correct steps?

Comment: Adding custom attributes to user is fine but adding new DbContext is unnecessary and you can use existing DbContext.

Comment: So creating the custom user class was fine but I didn't need the new Context, got it. Thank you for all your help.